# Is there an easy way to populate a ListView with Cursor?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I was wondering if there is a easy way to fill ListView with Cursor, like you can do with EditText:

```
final EditText visnavn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.visnavn);

DBAdapter db;

Cursor cur = db.findall();

            if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    visnavn.append(cur.getString(0));
                    visnavn.append(" ");
                    visnavn.append(cur.getString(1));
                    visnavn.append("\n");
                }while(cur.moveToNext());
            }
            cur.close();
```

I've tried something like this, with no luck:

```
    Cursor c = db.findAll();
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            list.add(c.getString(0));
            list.add(" ");
            list.add(c.getString(1));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
```

Comment: use an adapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Comment: so, no there is not?

Comment: it cant get much easier than using an adapter like you should

Comment: There is actually an easier way, I had to do that for a school project. I parsed a new XML file into a variable and filled that. After filling the parsed XML file, I added it to the list and voila. There it was, a listview full of records. :) I'll post the code as an solution!

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Oke, as I already said you in the comments that there is an easy way to load your Cursor data into your listview, here is the code I used. Maybe it's useful for you! :)

```
final Cursor locations = <get your data here>
locations.moveToFirst();
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
while ( locations.isAfterLast() == false ) {
    View tablerow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, null);
    TextView txtName = (TextView)tablerow.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

    txtName.setText(locations.getString(1));
    sView.addView(tablerow);
    locations.moveToNext();
}
```